# Где нужны запятые, а где они лишние?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

"Он будет по размеру либо как твой дом, либо чуть больше".

Нужна ли запятая перед «как»? И если есть лишние запятые, то тоже скажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Он будет по размеру либо как твой дом, либо чуть больше.***

Лишних запятых здесь нет, а запятую перед ***как*** поставить не получится – связку "либо как" невозможно разделить. Перед ***либо*** тоже нельзя, так как без оборота предложение не будет иметь смысла.

[**Сравнительный оборот**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147)

> 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом ***как*** не выделяется **запятыми:**
>    <...>
>    **4)** если сравнительный оборот входит в сказуемое (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота): <...>
>    *Лоб **был как белый мрамор**; Этот звук **был как звонок** будильника.*

[**Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#)

> 1. Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимися союзами ***и…и, да…да, ни…ни, или…или, либо…либо, то…то, не то…не то*** и др., ставится **запятая:** <...>
>    *С чужими я **либо** робел, **либо** важничал* (М. Г.).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142372/discussion-on-answer-by---------).